# Applying a function to various keys in a dictionary at a time

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary, key

How can I update the print_quiz_averages function so that it will print all scores for each person at a time, instead of showing every person's score for each item?

```
from __future__ import division

def main():
    quiz_averages = quiz_average(remove_zeros([57,0,36,29,38,31,33,0,42,0,52,28,0,50,26,97,80,63,8,36,33,39,12,36,12,59,75,61,57,39,18,9,19,35,75,5,18,0,56,0,24,0,9],
                                              [83,0,64,45,66,82,52,0,43,0,53,49,43,82,44,74,74,58,52,52,60,18,24,34,19,42,72,65,79,99,75,24,35,70,74,43,55,0,82,0,34,0,22],
                                              [69,0,38,16,16,16,55,0,28,0,44.5,31,0,33,52,75,46,33,36,0,49,34.5,35,79.5,13,27,31,52,40.5,64.5,15,0,31,47,26,0,36,0,68,0,64.5,0,20],
                                              [86,0,95,74,90,53,32,0,79,0,38,63,0,42,61,0,0,70,62,78,0,60,47,89,75,62,84,62,71,80,73,0,31,25,74,0,77,0,90,0,78,0,25]))
    student_quiz_scores = {'Raven':[61,65,52,62],
                           'Jacob':[39,99,64.5,80],
                           'Jessica':[35,70,47,25],
                           'Joe':[57,79,40.5,71],
                           'Aaron':[18,75,15,73]}
    print_quiz_averages(student_quiz_scores,quiz_averages)

def quiz_average(all_quizzes):
    averages = []
    for each_quiz in all_quizzes:
        each_average = find_average(each_quiz)
        averages.append(each_average)
    return averages

def print_quiz_averages(student_quiz_scores,the_averages):
    for i, average in enumerate(the_averages):
        print "\nThe average for quiz",i+1,"is:",average
        for student, student_data in student_quiz_scores.iteritems():
            if student_data[i]>average:
                print student, "got a",student_data[i],"which is",(str(student_data[i]-average))+"%", "higher than the average. :)"
            else:
                print student, "got a", student_data[i], "which is", (str(-student_data[i]+average))+"%", "lower than the average. :("

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Mmm ... homework ...  What do you mean by "at a time"?  Do you want all the numbers to print on top of each other?  On the same line?  One after the other without any English in the middle?

Comment: @dg99: It's not homework, just an exercise to practice Python. I want to print for example: (There should be a empty line after each smiley face, and show the data for the remaining 4 people after)

Ravi: 

The average for quiz 1 is: 38.8055555556
You did 22.1944444444 points higher than the average! :)

The average for quiz 2 is: 55.1891891892
You did 9.81081081081 points higher than the average! :)

The average for quiz 3 is: 40.0606060606
You did 11.9393939394 points higher than the average! :)

The average for quiz 4 is: 65.3548387097
You did 3.35483870968 points lower than the average! :(

Comment: Instead of running the `student loop` inside of `average loop` you should run `student loop` outside and `average loop` as nested loop...

Comment: @adil: I am not following, can you please show me the code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @adil said - switch your nested loops. Using your code example above...

```
for student, student_data in student_quiz_scores.iteritems():
    for i, average in enumerate(the_averages):
        print "\nThe average for quiz",i+1,"is:",average
        if student_data[i]>average:
            print student, "got a",student_data[i],"which is",(str(student_data[i]-average))+"%", "higher than the average. :)"
        else:
            print student, "got a", student_data[i], "which is", (str(-student_data[i]+average))+"%", "lower than the average. :("
```

Naturally, you will have to change some of the strings if you want the wording to appear exactly as stated in the example in your comment (as well as add spaces and such).